# navigator.splashscreen.hide() not working on cordova-android@11.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I just upgraded to cordova-android@11.0.0 targeting API 31. This required replacing the splash screen plugin from my previous builds. I use `AutoHideSplashScreen = false` so that I can hide the splash screen after the UI is rendered. This works fine on iOS but the splash screen persists forever on Android despite calls to `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` (even with the debugger). This happened both on API 31 and older devices. I resorted to auto-hide with a long fade for now, to get something working. I tried several different config.xml variants so I'm not sure whether putting one here will be useful, but for all of them `AutoHideSplashScreen = false` on Android did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to modify that in your
platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml file

this is how mine looks

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/cdv_splashscreen_background</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_cdv_splashscreen</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
```

***Please consider only the splash screen part***

Answer (score -1):

You need to set it up in your config.xml

```
 <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Comment: I tried exactly that and it worked on iOS but not on Android.

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug  : https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1463